# Java Swing: handling user input across different cards

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm pretty new to Java and I'm working on a program for which I have designed a GUI using a card layout. This is the [main window of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjIdu.png).

So far I have gotten the program to display properly and I can switch between cards and exit, but I am having issues handling user input. For example, on one card I have a text field and a submit button that saves the input to a string, but I can't figure out how to display that string in an uneditable text field on another card. The input seems to be saved to the string because I can print it to the console, but it doesn't show up in the GUI. I feel like maybe I have to repaint it or something, but so far I haven't gotten it to work.

I have done this all within basically one file (making each card a separate JPanel), but I am wondering if I have to make separate classes for each card/window, rather than them just being different panels within a single JFrame.

**Is it possible—within one file—to design a GUI based on a card layout in which one card is able to display user input from another card?** If so, do I need to refresh the panels or the frame so that the new data is represented? Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

Here's my main method, one of the windows, and some of the event handling, for some context:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    Object source = e.getSource();

    if(source == newClass){
        contentPaneLayout.show(contPane, "Add Class Card");
    }

    if(source == cancel || source == cancel2 || source == topMenu ||
        source == topMenu2 || source == topMenu3 ||source == topMenu4){
        contentPaneLayout.show(contPane, "Main Card");
    }

    if(source == create){
        cName = (String)classInput.getText();
        contentPaneLayout.show(contPane, "Main Card");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    contPane = frame.getContentPane();
    contPane.setLayout(contentPaneLayout=new CardLayout());
    ActionListener act = new Project();

    JPanel mainCard = mainWindow();
    JPanel classCard = createClassWindow();
    JPanel loadCard = loadWindow();
    JPanel addCard = addStudentsWindow();
    JPanel labCard = labWindow();
    JPanel sortCard = sortWindow();
    JPanel viewCard = viewDeleteWindow();

    newClass.addActionListener(act);
    loadStudents.addActionListener(act);
    addStudents.addActionListener(act);
    addScores.addActionListener(act);
    sortStudents.addActionListener(act);
    viewStudents.addActionListener(act);
    backupStudents.addActionListener(act);
    exit.addActionListener(act);
    cancel.addActionListener(act);
    cancel2.addActionListener(act);
    topMenu.addActionListener(act);
    topMenu2.addActionListener(act);
    topMenu3.addActionListener(act);
    topMenu4.addActionListener(act);
    create.addActionListener(act);
    load.addActionListener(act);
    saveStudent.addActionListener(act);

    contPane.add("Main Card", mainCard);
    contPane.add("Add Class Card", classCard);
    contPane.add("Load Students Card", loadCard);
    contPane.add("Add Students Card", addCard);
    contPane.add("Add Lab Scores Card", labCard);
    contPane.add("Sort Students Card", sortCard);
    contPane.add("View/Delete Students Card", viewCard);
    contentPaneLayout.show(contPane, "Main Card");

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(800, 300);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static JPanel createClassWindow()
{
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel flowPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    JLabel topLabel = new JLabel("<html><font size=5><b>Create a new class</b></html>");
    topLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    panel.add(topLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();

    JLabel classLabel = new JLabel("Class name: ");
    classInput.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);

    flowPanel.add(classLabel);
    flowPanel.add(classInput);
    panel.add(flowPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    buttonPane.add(create);
    buttonPane.add(cancel);
    panel.add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    return panel;
}
```

**Update:**

This is the event handling for the button that is supposed to set the string. String cName, JTextField classInput, and CardLayout contentPaneLayout are global variables. The string is set for console purposes, but the main card is shown without changes. I tried putting a repaint here, but it didn't seem to work.

```
    if(source == create){
    cName = (String)classInput.getText();
    contentPaneLayout.show(contPane, "Main Card");
    }
```

Here's where I want to display the user input in the "main card" panel:

```
    JLabel className = new JLabel("Class name");
    JTextField classNameInput = new JTextField(10);
    classNameInput.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
    classNameInput.setEditable(false);
    classNameInput.setText(cName);
```

Comment: It's hard to help you with the relevant parts of the code missing. Can you boil it down to where you read the text from input and try to display output? The layout itself isn't that relevant here.

Comment: I added more specific code snippets, hopefully they help illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 2):

> I am wondering if I have to make separate classes for each card/window, rather than them just being different panels within a single JFrame.

That depends on the size and structure of your application but making separate classes etc. will probably help you better organize and structure your code and thus will make it easier to understand.

As an example I'd not use the same `ActionListener` for all of your buttons and check the source inside `actionPerformed` but provide a separate listener (could  be inline classes but maybe better top level classes, i.e. ones with own files) for each button.

> Is it possible—within one file—to design a GUI based on a card layout in which one card is able to display user input from another card?

Yes it should be possible, independent of the class/file layout. You only need to propagate the input to where it should be displayed and trigger repaint correctly.

**Update:**

According to your edit you either create a new instance for `classNameInput` which is quite strange or you only call the last snippet where you create `classNameInput` only once.

In the former case you're probably not replacing the old instance with the current one in the card and thus see the "old" instance with it's "old" value. If you're asking yourself why you should replace the instance in the card or why this feels somewhat awkward the answer is: because it's awkward and probably not working as you intend. You'd normally keep a reference to `classNameInput` somewhere, e.g. in the main class or better in the class that defines the main panel (here subclassing `JPanel` would come in handy) and access it that way, e.g. by calling `getMainPanel().getClassNameInput().setText(classInput.getText())`.

In the latter case you're just assigning a new value to `cName` in the listener but you don't set the text on `classNameInput`. One solution would be as described above, i.e. you get the reference to `classNameInput` and call `setText(cName)` on it in the listener.

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot. I was concerned that I might be trying to do something that isn't possible. I will look at my code again with your help in mind.